# Why set this value to negative for a background image?

Tags: html, css

```
background: #f0f0f0 url(/tile.gif) repeat -70% 0;
```

What is the -70% doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's moving the background image right by 70% relative to it's current position.

This is useful for placing a tricky background image in the right position, or to achieve a certain effect.

Comment: I'm pretty sure its moving it horizontally.